# if Condition for this query

Tags: sql-server

How to do if condition for this query....if record not exist then insert else update from this select

```
 SELECT CAST(left(TerminalName, patindex('%[^0-9]%', TerminalName+'.') - 1) as int)
      ,'04944700'
      ,SUBSTRING(TerminalName , CHARINDEX('-' , TerminalName) + 1, LEN(TerminalName))
      ,TerminalName
      ,'Bulk'
      ,'0010'
      ,user
      ,GETDATE()
      ,user
      ,GETDATE()
FROM External_Blk_Itm_Contracts WHERE TerminalName NOT IN (SELECT MBFTERMINALNAME FROM budterminals)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the [MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) statement. Your Select statement will be the your source of data, and then you will insert or update depending on whether a row matching the join condition exists.

Here is an example from T-SQL I wrote:

```
MERGE ODS.dbo.Mytable as [Target]
    USING [Source Query] as [Source]
    ON [Target].SubId = [Source].SubId And [Target].WorkflowId = [Source].WorkflowId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT
        (
             [SubId]
            ,[WorkflowId]
            ,[ReadTime]
            ,[ReadTimeLocal]
        )
        VALUES
        (
             [SubId]
            ,[WorkflowId]
            ,[ReadTime]
            ,[ReadTimeLocal]
        )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE Set
        [Target].ReadTime = [Source].ReadTime,
        [Target].ReadTimeLocal = [Source].ReadTimeLocal,
    ;
```